# Overall minimizer of the minus log-likelihood of joint Gaussian distribution

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, normal-distribution, log-likelihood

Consider the following model. There is a DAG $D_0$ whose p nodes correspond to random variables $X_1,...,X_p$: assume that

$$X_1,...,X_p \sim N_p (0, \Sigma_0) \text{ with density } f_{ \Sigma_0} (\cdot),$$

$$N_p (0, \Sigma_0) \text{ is Markovian with respect to } D_0,$$

where the Markov property can be understood as the factorization property where the joint Gaussian density $f_{ \Sigma_0} (x_1,...,x_p) = \prod_{j=1}^p f_{ \Sigma_0} (x_j | x_{pa(j)})$, with pa(j) denoting the set of parents of node j.

A Gaussian DAG model in the above can always be equivalently represented as a linear structural equation model,

$$X_j = \sum\limits_{k \in \text{pa}(j)} \beta_{kj} X_k + \epsilon_j   \qquad  (    j=1,...,p),$$

where $\epsilon_1,..., \epsilon_n$ are independent, $\epsilon_j \sim N(0, |\omega_j|^2)$ and $\epsilon_j$ independent of $\{   X_k; k \in \text{pa}(j)   \}$; note that $\text{pa}(j) = \text{pa}_{D_0}(j)$ depends on the true DAG $D_0$.   Let

$$\Sigma_n := X^T X/n$$

be the empirical covariance matrix based on the observations X. Given a $p \times p$ nonsingular covariance matrix $\Sigma$, with inverse $\Theta := \Sigma^{-1}$, the minus log-likelihood is proportional to

$$l_n (\Theta):=  \text{trace}(\Theta \Sigma_n) - \log \det (\Theta).$$
Note that $\Theta_0 := \Sigma_0^{-1} $  is the overall minimizer of   $l(\Theta)$.

**Why this is the minimizer?**